# Timedelta only shows 2 digits in some cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I got the following lines of code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def my_function():
    start_time = datetime.now()

    # Do something

    end_time = datetime.now()

    return (end_time - start_time).microseconds

print(my_function)
```

If the function executes "slow enough", I manage to get output like `906` or `1021`. But sometimes, if I execute the function, I simply got the result `0`, no matter if I use other methods as well, like:

```
    return (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
```

or:

```
    return (end_time - start_time) * 1000
```

I sometimes still get just `0` as output. Can anyone tell me how I'm able to retrieve the time delta in any case?

Any help would be apprechiated. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you do you can have a look at the `time` module and look at the following functions `time.time()`, `time.perf_counter()` or even `time.perf_counter_ns()`

For instance

```
import time

def my_function():
    start_time = time.perf_counter_ns()

    # Do something

    end_time = time.perf_counter_ns()

    return (end_time - start_time) / 1_000_000 # if you want result in ms

my_function()
```